# Rails how to associate 2 models on create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to associate Order object wit  Dispute Object on create of Dispute but when i go create the object in the log shows:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Order without an ID)

should i not try to find the order in the method?

Someone know how to associate the objects in the creation?

the Dispute Controller is:

```
class DisputesController < ApplicationController

  def new

    if current_user.address.blank?
      redirect_to edit_user_path

      flash[:error] = 'fill the address'
    else
      @dispute = Dispute.new

    end
  end 



def create
 @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  if   current_user == @order.buyer
    dispute = @order.dispute.nil? ? Dispute.new : @order.dispute
    dispute.attributes = params[:dispute]
    dispute.user = @order.buyer
    dispute.buyer_name = @order.buyer_name
    dispute.seller_name = @order.seller_name

    if dispute.save
      flash[:success] = 'Dispute Created'
    end

end
```

The order model

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

has_one :dispute

end
```

the dispute model

```
class Dispute < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :order

end
```

Comment: `id` doesn't have a value in create method.

Comment: @Saibot, so i can't find on the create method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without adding parameters or a nested route the request won't know what order is being referenced. You can use nested routes like orders/:order_id/dispute (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) and then you can use @order.build_dispute (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-belongs-to)

Comment: yes, you are right! that's seems the only way to get the order id

Answer (score 0):

My first thought based on the error you are getting is to check what params you have available upon the form's submission, because it seems it is not finding an Order based on the param you're passing into the find call.

Also check out strong params for security: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Comment: Riley Thompson yes, so how can check which params are avaible?

Comment: Look into a debugging tool like Pry or ByeBug. They are a simple gem that will stop your code in the middle of execution, and you can call the params hash to see what it is populated with. Also, I believe the rails error messages will include the params values when it throws an error in some cases. So in this case I would stick a call to Binding.pry if  I was using pry right at the top of your create method in that controller. I'd then boot up my local server and submit the form, it will then hit that action and you will have a new pry session in your command line to call available variables.

Comment: Riley, thank you but i'm using Rails 3. so, Strong Parameters is not the concern here.

Comment: Riley  thank you. i already use ByeBug. but know i'll try pry too. to understand better how to debug

Comment: No problem, look into joshuacroyenmeyer's answer as well.  I probably assumed too much of your routes knowledge